# pyarrow.parquet.write_to_dataset() extremely slow when using partition_cols

Tags: python, pyarrow

I am toying around with parquet files in order to understand if they fit for my purposes. To do so, I load a dataset from a csv file and save it as a parquet dataset:

```
import pandas as pd          # version 0.25
import pyarrow as pa         # version 0.15
import pyarrow.parquet as pq

df = pd.read_csv('my.csv')

df_table = pa.Table.from_pandas(df)
pq.write_to_dataset(df_table, root_path='my.parquet')
```

This works fine and quite fast (~ 1 minute). However, when I try to write a partitioned parquet dataset like this,

```
pq.write_to_dataset(df_table, root_path='my.parquet', partition_cols=['id'])
```

it takes more than half an hour. This seems odd. I tried to set the `id` column as index, but that did not change much. Am I missing something?

Some background on the file: ~ 5 million rows, 9 columns. The `id` column contains ~ 330,000 different values. Is it just a bad idea to partition a dataset into such small pieces?

---

I am pretty new to Python (I use version 3.6.4) so I'm not sure if I provided all relevant information. Please comment if something is missing.

---

**EDIT:**
I found that fewer, larger chunks are faster in my case. This leads to the question of optimal chunk size. Where can I find information on this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

At ~15 (5 Million / 330K) rows per file, yes it is a bad idea to use parquet for such small files.  There is overhead for metadata in parquet and the amount of compression will be limited.  Based on the [Parquet Documentation](https://parquet.apache.org/documentation/latest/) row group sizes of ~512-1024MB is preferred, but this is due to HDFS.  So different storage scenarios might warrant different sizes.  In general, it probably doesn't make sense for files less then 10's of megabytes.

Comment: Thanks for the link to the documentation. Must have missed that before. So my takeaway for working with parquet files on a local machine is: Choose the chunk size as big as possible but small enough to fit as many chunks into RAM as you have cores on your machine. Does this make sense?

Comment: That seems like good rule of thumb but I think it is probably workload dependent (e.g. how many columns do you read back at a time).